# How to reduce size of apk after including QuickBlox video chat "so" driver files

Tags: quickblox-android

We have developed an Android application that leverages QuickBlox for implementing a Video Conference solution. However, issue is that the the driver files add an additional 15MB to the apk size which is highly undesirable. Is there a way to reduce the size of apk to <10MB?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using ProGuard or removing debug info?

Comment: I did try but unfortunately proguard does not optimize driver files

Answer (score 0):

You can use new feature in android gradle plugin - APK splits: 
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits. It’s a relatively new feature added to the Android Gradle plugin that promises to deliver one APK per CPU. 

You can enable ABI splitting in the build.gradle file like this:

```
android {
    // Some other configuration here...
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips'
            universalApk false
        }
    }
}
```